How to run a QT app on HDMI screen without login with Raspbian Lite?
I have Raspbian Lite OS installed and can access it via HDMI on a monitor as well as through SSH from my PC.
What I'd like to achieve is to have a QT app automatically displayed on the HDMI output when Raspbian starts so I can make a kiosk system.
Currently, I can run the app if I call from SSH  /home/pi/arholding/arholding -platform eglfs -fullscreen, and it shows on the HDMI display but only after I log in via HDMI.
However, I'd like the app to launch and be visible without having to log in on the HDMI side, but without disabling the SSH login password.
Is there a way to do this?

what DE are you using?
